# Expand 1D Numpy array into 2D array of groups of 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Original

```
a = np.arange(1, 10)
```

Expected output

```
b = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
   [ 2,  3,  4],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 4,  5,  6],
   [ 5,  6,  7],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 7,  8,  9],
   [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

I can achieve this using

```
b = np.array([a[i:i+3] for i in range(10-3)])
```

but I was wondering if anyone knew a numpy vectorized function to avoid the list comprehension and conversion to array

Comment: The best answer in the above question can be used to do this with a stride of 1.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.